# Getting nested <li> tags also.....just need the direct <li> item

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a page structure where it includes hyperlinks with different levels of nested list items. I am writing the `xpath` for just the second nested list items(level 2) but it is also giving me all the list items below level 2(level 3 or below), which i don't need. It's getting really frustrating now because I have tried different `xpaths` and `cssSelectors`, everytime it is taking the level 3 list items along with level 2.

The page structure is exactly like following:

```
<div>
     <ul class="menuBar_menu_lvl_0">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
          <ul class="menu_lvl_1">
            <li class="item_lvl_2"></li>
            <li class="item_lvl_2"></li>
            <li class="item_lvl_2">
               <ul class="menu_lvl_2">
                 <li class="item_lvl_3"></li>
                 <li class="item_lvl_3"></li>
                 <li class="item_lvl_3"></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">

xpath = //ul[@class="menuBar_menu_lvl_0"]//li[@class="item_lvl_1"]//ul[@class="menu_lvl_1"]//li[@class="item_lvl_2"]
```

This is also giving me item number 3 elements along with item level 2. I want to get each level item correctly and separately. Anybody's help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What's the reason for the `maven` tag?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Check http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/21ebf85f4c5f6758fd62be1fb4a7ba6e

Comment: @Alejandro I am sorry for being very less descriptive in this but i the html of the page that i am working on looks exactly the same. the problem is that i just wanna get level_1 <li> items and nothing more. If you can suggest me an xpath for this problem it'll be great.

Comment: You say you only want level 1 `LI` items but your XPath shows you trying to get `li[@class="item_lvl_2"]`... which is NOT a level 1 `LI`. This can't be the exact structure of the HTML you are working with because NONE of the first level `LI`s are properly closed. It would be better if you put text into each of the `LI`s you want and then show your expected output. Right now everyone is guessing because the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
Here is the sample that used.

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div>
     <ul class="menuBar_menu_lvl_0">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
          <ul class="menu_lvl_1">
            <li class="item_lvl_2">Level1-li1</li>
            <li class="item_lvl_2">Level1-li2</li>
            <li class="item_lvl_2">
               <ul class="menu_lvl_2">
                 <li class="item_lvl_3">Level2-li1</li>
                 <li class="item_lvl_3">Level2-li2</li>
                 <li class="item_lvl_3">Level2-li1</li>
               </ul>
               Level1-li3
            </li>
          </ul>
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
       <li class="item_lvl_1">
         </ul>
</div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

And below is the xpath

```
//ul[@class='menu_lvl_1']//li[not(parent::ul[@class='menu_lvl_2'])]
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Here is the method to get the text from parent element only.

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

Comment: thanks
but I need that "menu_lvl_1" list item which has further levelling, I just don't need the items of the further levels of "menu_lvl_1".
The solution that you gave is returning just the "menu_lvl_1" items that don't have any further levelling. Plus this solution is getting the element on chrome but returning a null text everytime.

Comment: Ok, try this `//ul[@class="menu_lvl_1"]//li[not(parent::ul[@class='menu_lvl_2'])]`.  I don't see any text for all lis (at least in the code that you provided)

Comment: check the updated answer with the screenshot and the source used for test.

Comment: I tries this as well
onchrme it is showing all the menu_level_1 items but when I am running it, it is also giving me the menu_level_2 items along with each menu_level_1 item in corresponding manner. I think i have to split my answer with "\n" to just get the first line in my string text, which is what i need. I just wanted to know why I am getting it all together.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you look at my screenshot, I am using my custom method to get the text form the parent node only. That's why I got the desired out. If you want I can share the method which I wrote to get only parent text, ignores the children.

Comment: yes of course, that'll be great if you can share that.

Comment: Done, updated the answer with the method. Let me know how it goes.